# Форма отправляет данные в кодировке Windows-1252, хотя сайт работает в Windows-1251

Tags: битрикс, php, формы, форма

Приветствую уважаемые Hash-кодеры!

Проблема следующая - контактная Форма (а в прочим и любая другая на сайте) отправляет данные в кодировке Windows-1252, не смотря на то что сам сайт находится в кодировке Windows-1251 + я указал атрибут у самой формы **accept-charset="windows-1251"**. Ничего не помогает. сайт suhpay точка ru (не хочу указывать ссылку на сайт, чтобы потом поисковые роботы не находили её тут и не приводили не релевантный трафик на сайт), форма внизу сайта. Как я узнал что данные уходят в windows-1252? С помощью firebug посмотрел какие данные отправляет форма в обработчик и распознал этот код через декодер Артемия Лебедева, который показал CP1252 → CP1251.

Сайт сделан на основе 1С Битрикс, редакция первый сайт, работает в кодировке Windows-1251.

Comment: Дело ваше, но я бы вам советовал использовать utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте проверить кодировку этого файла, **notepad++**, например, и в нем же поменять, если что. Так же проверьте **http** заголовки и **html** тег

```
<meta charset="кодировка">
```

(сорян в коменты не могу писать)

Answer (score 0):

может быть у вас есть такой файлик как config? В нем часто указывают кодировку сайта. Или htaccess?

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251');
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

mysql_connect($host, $login, $pass) or die ('Не удалось подключиться к Базе Данных');
  mysql_query('SET Names cp1251');
  mysql_select_db($db) or die ('Базы Данных не существует!');

Посмотрите, может чего и найдется))

Comment: нет там что-то другое, htaccess и прочие известные методы уже перепробовал